# Bash: How to cd to subdirectory using find?

Tags: linux

I use `cd` to a folder with many numbered subfolders. How can I use `find` to find a subfolder that begins with a certain number and `cd` to that subfolder?

Here is what I have currently but it says cd: too many arguments

```
cd folder
cd $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "$NUM*")
```

I used `maxdepth` because I didn't want to recursively search inside the subfolders. `$NUM` is a variable that I specify each time I run this script.

Comment: That actually works for me; the only problem I can see is that `find` might return more than one match ... ?

Comment: Be prepared for a bit of a surprise when find returns nothing.

Comment: When you use the wildcard `*`, expect the possibility that you get more than one result. As evidently happens here.

Comment: If you just need or can accept the first result from find, use `find ... | head -n 1`.

Comment: But you still need to check for the situation when your `find` returns nothing. Otherwise, what will happen, is that your command will become `cd` which in effect will cd to your home directory, *i.e., you will NOT be in* `folder` *anymore*.

Comment: look for sentence construction and make it meaningful.